# Express, app.listen not hitting callback, no error either

Tags: node.js, express

I'm starting to learn Node.js because up until this point my knowledge of programming is only front-end stuff.

Already before even getting through the "Hello world" example, I've run into a problem.
My code is :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(4600,"localhost", (req,res) => {
console.log('Server Running');
});
```

In terminal, node -v gives me back v12.16.2.
when I run node .\server.js my app.listen callback is never called. Nothing shows in terminal or output of VSCode console. With no knowledge of debugging Node.js, I can't obviously see any error anywhere. When I go to localhost:4600, I just get "localhost refused to connect.". Does anyone know what might be obviously wrong? Or any way I can set up VSCode to at least get an error back on what might be happening in app.listen? Extremely novice question, but an answer could really help me out (and anyone down the road). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

app.listen accepts only two params. So try this code

```
app.listen(4600, () => {
console.log('Server Running');
});
```

[image]

If still this doesnot work pls try changing the port with my code... May be 4600 port is used by some other resources

Comment: Hi, have tried your code, thanks for the response. Unfortunately I couldnt get the Server Running to log to console even with trying several different ports :/

Answer (score -1):

try to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(4600,'127.0.0.1', (req,res) => {
console.log('Server Running');
});
```

Comment: Hi, have tried your code, thanks for the response. Unfortunately I couldnt get the Server Running to log to console even with trying several different ports :/

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by [@gvs-akhil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7737777/gvs-akhil), `app.listen()` accepts only two **required** parameters.

The complete syntax of the `app.listen()` (here, `app` being the variable initialized via express) is: `app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])`.

The general way of starting a server is as follows:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; // the process.env.PORT is optional for a beginner.

app.listen(PORT, (err) =>
    err
        ? console.error(`Error starting server: ${err}`)
        : console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

Now you can run your file (assuming it's named server.js as stated in the question):

```bash
node server.js
```

If the current port is in use then you can use a different port and can check out the ports in use via the terminal:

```bash
netstat
```

The expected output should look something like this (I've named my file `index.js`):

[Express server running output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruvj0.png)